# IPython startup script: Check if QtConsole

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jupyter

For my IPython QtConsole, I have a startup script in my `profile_default/startup` folder, which contains the following lines:

```
ipy = get_ipython()

try:
    plot
except NameError:  #  not loaded yet
    ipy.run_line_magic("pylab", "inline")
```

This works fine in the QtConsole and Notebook, but if I now run `ipython` with no subcommand, i.e. in the Windows command line, it prints an error that the 'inline' GUI is invalid.

Is there any way I can check for the subcommand (qtconsole, notebook or "None") inside the startup script, so I can avoid that message?

(IPython QtConsole 3.2.0, WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4)

Comment: Added `ipy = get_ipython()`, which I forgot, as @Matt correctly assumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `ipy` is the result of `get_ipython()`.

Warning: You should not try to have code that behave differently on various frontend. It *will* break at some point, and lead to hard to debug issues that don't make sens. [Nasal demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) will be on a the lookout for the smallest misstep to haunt you.

That being say, in the pure, classical terminal IPython  you can can verify that:

```
In [1]: type(get_ipython())
Out[1]: IPython.terminal.interactiveshell.TerminalInteractiveShell
```

Which is not true for Notebook and QtConsole (which are `ZMQInteractiveShell`). In both case `IPython.terminal.interactiveshell.TerminalInteractiveShell` should be importable, and you can check with `issubclass` in which case you are.

Now, you can also create your own aliases on windows (not sure how), that pass extra command line arguments to IPython, in order for `notebook` and `qtconsole` to not have the same startup sequence.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I've seen other variables inside `get_ipython()` that appeared or disappeared depending on the frontend being used, but that was all a bit too vague to conclude sth. from it. I was hoping those command line flags could be somehow extracted, too. But yeah, the class type will do.

Comment: And regarding the undefined behavior: Generally you're right, but the pylab GUI backend is different for those frontends anyway, so I suppose that shouldn't break anything that isn't already.